# Can we use laravel 5 query builder for google big query data extraction?

Tags: laravel-5, google-bigquery

I am working on Google big queries and I wanted to know that either I can use laravel query builder to get data from google big query service?

Answer (score 4):

I was working on the same thing and trying to figure out the solution for that I user laravel 5 query builder and then I get an idea if we get the query from query builder and get bindings from query builder then we can easily use that query directory for the `google bigquery` Let me explain with the code below.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id','=','3');
```

Now i will use the function that will return me mysql query.

```
$sql = $users->toSql(); //this will return the sql query from query builder.
```

The output of above statement will be like this

```
select * from users where id = ?
```

Now I have another function that will give me the binding of that query.

```
$bindings = $users->getBindings(); //this statement will return me 3
```

After that if we want complete mysql query with binding then we have another function to do that.

```
public function getSqlWithBinding($sql,$bindDataArr){
    foreach($bindDataArr as $binding)
    {
        $value = is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'".$binding."'";
        $sql = preg_replace('/\?/', $value, $sql, 1);
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

Just pass both `$sql = $users->toSql();` and `$bindings = $users->getBindings();` in parameter to the above function and get the complete query like below.

```
select * from users where id = 3
```

Now that sql query you can use for you `google bigquery` without any confusion.

Comment: Even better BigQuery API query method allows you to pass the query and bindings separately. 
`$client->query($users->toSql())->parameters($users->getBindings());`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The query builder is meant for database protocols. Currently, Laravel supports four databases:

```
MySQL
PostgreSQL
SQLite
SQL Server
```

BigQuery instead is provided as a service, and has it's own SDK. You need to add the to composer.json the [BigQuery Cloud](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php) package.

Comment: It gives me an issue on localhost. Is it necessary to run the big query code on any server? I got this error.

`{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }`

Comment: it should not, make sure you set the service account credentials correctly

Comment: @Pntium10! I get the solution for that problem please see the above answer. Also thanks for your time.